# Jquery Error for Beginning Programmer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery. I am trying to test out my knowledge. But the following is not working on my page on an img (the only img on the page). I have checked the reference in the html document and it is correct.

I am getting an "unexpected token" error from chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
    $('img').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
});
$('img').mouseleave(function() {
    $('img').fadeTo('fast',1);
)};
});
```

Comment: `)};` should be `});`

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the `mouseleave` function using `})` not `)}`:

```
$('img').mouseleave(function() {
    $('img').fadeTo('fast',1);
}); // <-- Here
```

Also, it's better to use `$(this)` to target only the targeted image:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
    $('img').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
});
```

and you can also use **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** to shorten your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: And probably use `$(this)`in the `.mouseleave()` function. Prevents jQuery from finding the `<img>`again, would be more efficient.

Comment: Could save some code by using `.hover()` or chaining event handlers.

Comment: Thank you so much, those symbols are so similar I didn't even think to check them

Comment: jfriend, how would I go about using the .hover() so that the mouseleave effect also happens?

Comment: @user3583236: See https://api.jquery.com/hover/